# Find k integers that can make up all integers below N.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

For given $N$, what is the smallest $k$ so that we can find $k$ natural numbers satisfiying some of these $k$ numbers can add up to any $i$ for $1\leq i\leq N$. Moreover, how to find all possible $k$ numbers?

Comment: $k$ and $N$ are natural numbers? Do you have any more information about $k$ and $N$? Because if I understand you correctly, it should be easy to find pairs of $k$ and $N$ where this doesn't work (large $N$ and small $k$)

Comment: @Hirshy Sorry I didn't make it clear. Here $k$ should be the smallest natural number that can satisfy the condition: there exist $k$ natural numbers that can make up all integers between $1$ and $N$. This means that if $N$ is given, $k$ is fixed.

Comment: @Blex Actually it's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: So your question should read something like "for given $N\in\mathbb N$ what is the smallest $k\in\mathbb N$, so that..." ?

Comment: An example can be easily constructed using binary. But for arbitary $N$, binary is not the way that makes $k$ the smallest.

Comment: @Hirshy Yes, I have edited the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If you have $k$ numbers then there are $2^k-1$ subsets of those numbers. So you can hope to be able to make up at most $2^k-1$ different integers (possibly less if some different subsets make up the same integers.

With this in mind if we have $k$ integers and $2^k<N+1$ we cannot hope to make up all integers below $N$. So we need $2^k\geq N+1\iff k\geq  \log_2(N+1)$. Hence the least possible value of $k$ is $\lceil \log_2(N+1) \rceil$.

If we set $k$ to this value then taking the $k$ integers $1,2,4\dots 2^{k-1}$ will allow us to make up all numbers between $2^k-1$ and $1$. Since $2^k\geq N+1$ this allows us to express every number $i$ with $1\leq i\leq N$

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is well known that  1,2,4, ... $2^k$, $2^k -1 \not\lt N$ does the trick.

1+2+4+ .... to k terms is a G.P. with a = 1, r = 2, S(k) = $\dfrac{2^k - 1}{2-1} = 2^k - 1$,

Suppose numbers from 1 through $2^k - 1$ are covered, then  the next term, $2^k$ ensures an unbroken chain covered upto $2^{k+1} -1$

But {1,2} covers all numbers upto $2^2 - 1$, hence proved

**PS:**

For an arbitrary number N, **not** of the form $2^k - 1$, I can't find a general rule to minimize *k*

Comment: yes, although you need to prove it.

Comment: But for $N \neq 2^k -1$, this was not the best way to minimize $k$.

Comment: @LouisYu are you sure?

Comment: @LouisYu: Care to elaborate. Any collection of $k$ numbers has $2^k-1$ non-empty subsets, and thus you cannot go higher than $2^k-1$.

Comment: @dREaM I get it. $k$ is the smallest using binary. The second question is how to find all possible $k$ numbers.